# Crop image ala Google Goggles

Tags: android, image-processing, crop, google-goggles

I'm trying to do some ROI (region of interest) selection in my app, but I don´t know, how to create some kind of resizable (by fingers) rectangle like you can see in Google Goggles. 
Can you help me? Is there any source code example?

Comment: any chance you can post your moveCorner and setCorner methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My final solution is to draw and rectangle in the midle of a view and implement onTouchEvent() in my activity to set new corners coordinates like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    if(SETTING_ROI == true){
        if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            START_DRAGGING = true;
            myView.selectCorner((int) me.getRawX(), (int) me.getRawY()); // selecst nearest corner
        }
        if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_MOVE");
            myView.moveCorner((int) me.getRawX(), (int) me.getRawY()); // move selected corner continuously
        }
        if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            if (START_DRAGGING == true) {
                START_DRAGGING = false;
                myView.moveCorner((int) me.getRawX(), (int) me.getRawY()); // final selected corner move
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you reuse code from the Gallery-Cropper?

The `CropImage` class source code is available [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery3D/+/master/src/com/cooliris/media/CropImage.java).

Comment: It seems too complex. I will better appreciate just an example of How to create an rectangle and move its corners to all directions to create an custom selection.